# All Browsers(with all versions) in one program

Tags: html, browser, web

I have a local html which uses .png files and I want to check my html behavior on all browsers.Is there any program that includes well known browsers (Chrome-Mozilla-IE...etc) with versions of them ?

Comment: you can download, ieTester, Utilu IE collection, Utilu Mozilla collection its, try googling

Comment: Yeah I am downloading now Thanks @mack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The closest you will get is either an online service like Browsershots or Adobe Browser Lab (these probably require your files to be online).

A slightly better alternative is crossbrowsertesting.com which uses web based remote access to computers running all different browsers and OS. This will require your files to be online.

For basic IE testing you can use IE Tester as a standalone program but it is full of bugs and not very reliable. This will cope with local files but only includes IE 5.5 to IE10.